# Luminace HDR , Qt5

Tags: qt5

I  was installing `luminance hdr` by using the command `cmake src`

I Got error :

```
CMake Error at Libpfs/CMakeLists.txt:15 (qt5_use_modules):
  Unknown CMake command "qt5_use_modules".
```

Then i tried to install qt5 modules:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev
```

But still getiing the same error . Plese Guide me appropriately.

Comment: What is the ubuntu version of your system?

Answer (score 0):

I did install qt manually into local folder and exported with CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. Also follow the outdated instructions and make an empty directory which you will enter before typing following (the path might of course vary depending on your system and where you download and extract the archive:

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/USER/downloads/qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/cmake/
cmake /home/USER/downloads/LuminanceHDR-master/
```

Yet I get some problems with running the application atm. with some symbol errors. But everything compiles fine after sorting out all dependencies (I skipped FITS support, but it should work without I guess).

Since this is a long time ago you asked for this, have you managed it somehow?